# Error using JMS Transaction - javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The session is closed

Tags: java, jms, mule

I am using JMS Polling to poll JMS queue every 5 minutes using below code. In the below code, I have set the polling frequency to 1 minute for testing. Polling is working fine but it is throwing below exception in logs. I am not able to figure out why it is doing like this. Tried to play around by changing some settings but could not figure out.

Please help me resolving this issue.

```
<jms:connector name="jmsConnector" jndiInitialFactory="${jndi.initialFactoryClass}" connectionFactoryJndiName="${jndi.connectionFactoryName}"
        jndiProviderUrl="${jms.brokerURL}" username="${jms.username}" password="${jms.password}" persistentDelivery="true" maxRedelivery="2" 
        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="5" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" specification="1.1" />

<service-overrides transactedMessageReceiver="com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver"/>

<jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${JMS_QUEUE}" exchange-pattern="one-way">
    <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
    <properties>
         <spring:entry key="pollingFrequency" value="60000" />
    </properties>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

Polling is working fine but it is throwing below exception in logs :

```
WARN  2013-05-02 10:33:05,072 [jmsConnector.receiver.03] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver: Error in TX notification handler.
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The session is closed.
    at progress.message.jimpl.Session.getJMSObjectClosedException(Session.java:3341)
    at progress.message.jimpl.Session.rollback(Session.java:1499)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver$2.onNotification(TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver.java:323)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver$2.onNotification(TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver.java:298)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Sender.dispatch(Sender.java:40)
    at org.mule.context.notification.Policy.dispatch(Policy.java:122)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.notifyListeners(ServerNotificationManager.java:249)
    at org.mule.context.notification.ServerNotificationManager.fireNotification(ServerNotificationManager.java:200)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.fireNotification(DefaultMuleContext.java:435)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractTransaction.fireNotification(AbstractTransaction.java:144)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractTransaction.rollback(AbstractTransaction.java:98)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractSingleResourceTransaction.rollback(AbstractSingleResourceTransaction.java:85)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionCoordination.resolveTransaction(TransactionCoordination.java:214)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.resolveTransactionIfRequired(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingJmsMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:84)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me looking into this issue.

Vijay

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning not an error: though a little scary, it's not an error as far as Mule is concerned. Maybe the Progress JMS client is a little finicky and doesn't behave the same way other JMS clients do, but again Mule isn't reporting an error so it should not impact your application.

I suggest you open a JIRA anyway so MuleSoft can look into the issue and maybe add support for this particular JMS client.

Comment: Thanks David. I will open a JIRA ticket for this issue.

Comment: Cool, please post the JIRA number so we can follow it.